# How to prevent Guid.NewGuid() from generating a second guid in the same instance?

Tags: c#

I find myself writing C# code and I am way out of my comfort zone. Happy to learn though.
Here's what I'm dealing with:

I have a variable that instantiates Guid.NewGuid() when it gets declared, like so:

```
var myNewId = Guid.NewGuid(); // {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

I have a second variable that receives the value of the first one and appends a generic string to it, like so:

```
var myOtherId = myNewId.ToString() + "_abc"; // expected: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000_abc
var myOtherId = myNewId.ToString() + "_abc"; // actual: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx_abc
```

The problem I have is that when the second variable references the first one, it appears that the first one gets instantiated again and I end up with a new Guid.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Guid.NewGuid() is a method that actually gives a unique ID when you run it, not a blank one for you to populate.

Comment: `Guid.NewGuid()` creates a single Guid instance, whose value is **never** `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`. All-zeroes is the default Guid value, returned by `Guid.Empty` or `default(Guid)`.

Comment: Post the real code, what you expected and what you got. What you claim can't be reproduced while the code you posted won't compile - you can't declare two variables with the same name in the same scope.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The two lines are meant to look at the comments behind them.

Comment: @LarsTech that's obvious. It's also obvious that the claim is wrong - `ToString()` doesn't initialize Guids. We are all trying to guess what the OP means, or come up with a scenario that would make sense even though the question is wrong. Perhaps there's a function that calls `Guid.NewGuid() and then returns the results of `myNewId.ToString()`. Perhaps the OP thought the call would return the same value each time? Or that `NewGuid()` is a default constructor?

Comment: Sorry guys. I was not clear enough. The "000..." and the "xxx..." are just for illustrations purposes.
I know that the method generates a "unique id", not zeros unless I use "Guid.Empty()".
Clearly I'm doing something wrong.
When I  reference the first variable in the value of the second one, the guid is different.

Comment: @RickRiggs. Thanks. I understand and that part works the way I need it.

Comment: It's not clear from your post what isn't working.

Comment: @TimSchmelter. It does not. The zeroes were just for illustration.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. What I expected is the the first variable would get a generated Guid. And when I reference the first variable in the value of the second one, I'd get what was originally generated and not a new one.
My perception is that when I reference the first variable, the "NewGuid" method gets instantiated again, Hence I get a new guid.
Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @jnkrois no it doesn't. Post the *actual* code. `Guid.ToString()` doesn't instantiate anything. `NewGuid()` does, but only when you explicitly call it. `NewGuid()` will never return an emtpy Guid.

Comment: @TimSchmelter. Although I'd love to get a ready made solution. I also want to understand the process. Can't expect my problems fixed for me all the time.
Thought that examples of code would give you an idea and suggest possible solutions.

Comment: @LarsTech. My apologies. What does not work is that I want 2 variables to have the same Guid. The first one by calling the method and the second one by assigning the generated guid from the fist one.
I end up with different guids in each variable.
Hope that makes sense.
Thanks

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(myNewId.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + myOtherId);` produces what you want, so it's not clear where your issue is.

Comment: @LarsTech. Thank you. I will look further into this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Guid.Empty`

```
var myNewId = Guid.Empty;
```

`Guid.NewGuid()` initializes a new instance of the Guid not an empty guid

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.empty?view=netframework-4.8
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=netframework-4.8